# Unable to understand the Asp.net MVC routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, routes, url-routing

I have added the following route to my global.asax file :-

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Admin_Route",
    "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    new[] { "PriceCompare.Admin.Controllers" }
    );

routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }, 
    new[] { "PriceCompare.Controllers" } 
    );
```

The admin controllers i.e. *ManageCatsController, ManageBrandsController, etc.* reside in **PriceCompare.Admin.Controllers** namespace and other general controllers reside in **PriceCompare.Controllers** namespace.

The problem is that i am able to visit all the controllers by adding ***Admin/*** in front of them, irrespective of whether they are in **PriceCompare.Admin.Controllers** namespace.

Also, I am able to visit admin controllers directly without prefixing ***Admin/***.

Why is this happening. Am i misunderstanding the routing behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to register your Admin area.

When I have registered routes for areas I've always done it like this:

Inside App/Areas/Admin folder create an AdminAreaRegistration.cs file with this in it...

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
namespace AppName.Areas.Admin
{
    public class AdminAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
    {
        public override string AreaName
        {
            get
            {
                return "Admin";
            }
        }

        public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
        {
            context.MapRoute(
                "Admin",
                "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { controller="Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                new string[] { "AppName.Areas.Admin.Controllers" }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Now do this in `Global.asax`:

```
protected void Application_Start()
    {
        // Add this next line
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

        // Add any other stuff (like IoC or whatever)
    }
```

And only register your normal routes in `RegisterRoutes` in `Global.asax`, like this:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }, // Parameter defaults
        new string[] { "AppName.Controllers" }
        );
 }
```

I would also recommend keeping the `Area` part inside your Admin namespace (so calling it `PriceCompare.Areas.Admin.Controller` in your case) as it will make life a lot easier later on when.

Please try this and let me know if it works :-)

Comment: I will have to change a lot: A complete new hierarchy. I tried `Areas` concept in a new mvc app and it works the way i need. Actually i bit baffled to understand why my current routing is behaving improperly. Why i am able to visit all controllerx by suffixing 'Admin/`. Infact the Areas concept, also make use of namespace i guess.

Comment: If you are specifying a whole other namespace which contains controllers `PriceCompare.Admin.Controllers` compared to `PriceCompare.controllers` then this does sound like you are using separate `Areas` as defined.  Don't be too disheartened; I had to make a similar change to a project and it didn't take that long. Just make sure you backup/commit whatever before you start. I'm glad the code worked in any case. Good luck! :-)